# build command with interleaved, repeated parameter names and argument values

Tags: git-bash

I'm using a tool called ROBOT to merge ontology files: http://robot.obolibrary.org/merge

It has an `--inputs` parameter that takes a wildcard, but that doesn't seem to work in my environment (GitBash in Windows 10).

How can I take a bunch of files like this

```
$ ls -1 *ttl
cl.owl.txt.ttl
efo.owl.txt.ttl
htn.owl.txt.ttl
```

And assemble a command in this general form?

```
$ ./robot merge \
--input cl.owl.txt.ttl \
--input efo.owl.txt.ttl \
--input htn.owl.txt.ttl \
--output merged.ttl
```

Using either single or double quotes doesn't seem to help:

```
$ jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java -Xms4G -Xmx8G -jar robot.jar merge --inputs "ontopath/*ttl"
UNKNOWN ARG ERROR unknown command or option: ontopath\efo.owl.txt.ttl
```

```
$ jdk1.8.0_201/bin/java -Xms4G -Xmx8G -jar robot.jar merge --inputs 'ontopath/*ttl'
UNKNOWN ARG ERROR unknown command or option: ontopath\efo.owl.txt.ttl
```

Comment: What was the command you tried to run with wildcards? Did you remember to quote the wildcard as shown in the documentation you link to?

Comment: `robot merge --inputs '*.ttl' --output merged.ttl`. Quote the pattern so that the shell does not expand it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write yourself a wrapper script that lets you build the argument list in such a way that it hopefully survives Windows Java's mangling of the wildcard argument. Here's a script `mergefiles`:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="$1"
shift
for file
do
  inputs+=( --input "$file" )
done

./robot merge "${inputs[@]}" --output "$output"
```

In Git Bash you should now be able to run `./mergefiles merged.ttl *.tll`

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the Windows command interpreter doesn't do glob expansion; it leaves that to the command receiving an argument like `*.ttl`. `bash`, however, expands a pattern and passes the resulting words as separate arguments. The following are equivalent:

```
robot merge --inputs *.ttl --output merged.ttl
robot merge --inputs cl.owl.txt.ttl efo.owl.txt.ttl htn.owl.txt.ttl --output merged.ttl
```

You need to quote the pattern so that it is passed *literally* to `robot` for it to expand:

```
robot merge --inputs '*.ttl' --output merged.ttl
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the GitBash shell, not cmd.exe (or whatever it's called now), if that makes a difference. See my edited question for notes on quoting.

Comment: Yikes. To me, that looks like the Java code is doing something wrong.

Comment: Java does the best it can with the unenviable task of bridging the gap between the Windows single string and Unix string array argument model. It's a mess.